# Does ffmpeg preset speed affects 2 pass encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg

If I'm encoding files like this:

```
ffmpeg -v quiet -hide_banner -y -i "$f" -passlogfile "$TEMP_FOLDER/ffmpeg.log" -c:v libx264 -b:v 2.5M -maxrate 2.5M -bufsize 5M -profile:v high -level 4.1 -pass 1 -sn -an -f matroska /dev/null < /dev/null
ffmpeg -v quiet -hide_banner -y -i "$f" -passlogfile "$TEMP_FOLDER/ffmpeg.log" -c:v libx264 -b:v 2.5M -maxrate 2.5M -bufsize 5M -profile:v high -level 4.1 -sn -an -pass 2 -f matroska "${f%.*}".h264 < /dev/null
```

Would setting preset speed increase quality? Should I use it on the first pass or the second ?

Comment: Yes, slower presets will yield better quality or a lower bitrate. Use in both passes.

Comment: Thanks Gyan! If you want to elaborate it and post it I can accept it as answer. I trust you :)